# Verify access token with Twitter

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth

I have a Web Api project that I have already configured to use Facebook & Google authentication.

Facebook and Google both have a way of verifying the access token given on authentication step.

Facebook:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token={0}&access_token={1}", accessToken, appToken
```

Google:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={0}", accessToken
```

These return the app_id or consumer key for my applications.

What is the process for Twitter?

The documentation I have read isn't very clear and what I have tried fails and returns a 404.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Verify Credentials](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/get-account-verify_credentials) endpoint:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json
```

This requires OAuth1A authorization and will verify the credentials of the authorizing user.